# Android app crashes by setting default values

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I try to set default values in my app.

I tried this:

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.defaults, false);
```

and this

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.defaults, false);
```

But it always crashes.

Here my res/xml/defaults.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="programTitles">["x", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]</string>
    <string name="programSubs">["", "as", "bs", "cs", "ds", "es"]</string>
</resources>
```

LogCat:

```
10-09 08:16:21.820: W/dalvikvm(1557): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a5fba8)
10-09 08:16:21.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1557): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-09 08:16:21.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1557): Process: com.example.blauzahn, PID: 1557
10-09 08:16:21.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1557): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.blauzahn/com.example.blauzahn.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class resources
10-09 08:16:21.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
10-09 08:16:21.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
10-09 08:16:21.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
10-09 08:16:21.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
10-09 08:16:21.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-09 08:16:21.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-09 08:16:21.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
10-09 08:16:21.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-09 08:16:21.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-09 08:16:21.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
10-09 08:16:21.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
10-09 08:16:21.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-09 08:16:21.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1557): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class resources
10-09 08:16:21.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItemFromTag(GenericInflater.java:441)
10-09 08:16:21.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:317)
10-09 08:16:21.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:263)
10-09 08:16:21.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at android.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:272)
10-09 08:16:21.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at android.preference.PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(PreferenceManager.java:485)
10-09 08:16:21.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at android.preference.PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(PreferenceManager.java:444)
10-09 08:16:21.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at com.example.blauzahn.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:79)
10-09 08:16:21.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
10-09 08:16:21.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-09 08:16:21.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
10-09 08:16:21.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     ... 11 more
10-09 08:16:21.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1557): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.preference.resources" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.blauzahn-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.blauzahn-1, /system/lib]]
10-09 08:16:21.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
10-09 08:16:21.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
10-09 08:16:21.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
10-09 08:16:21.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItem(GenericInflater.java:375)
10-09 08:16:21.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at android.preference.GenericInflater.onCreateItem(GenericInflater.java:417)
10-09 08:16:21.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItemFromTag(GenericInflater.java:428)
10-09 08:16:21.840: E/AndroidRuntime(1557):     ... 20 more
```

For me it seems like "resources" is a wrong tag or something like that. Is this so? Which tag do i need?

Comment: and where is your logcat then????

Comment: The string resource is an array?

Comment: `<string name="programTitles">["x", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]</string>` this is **not** a string-array.

Comment: Why is it not a string?

Comment: String arrays are declared inside `<string-array>` tags. See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray) for an example.

Comment: i know, but i wanna save a parsed json-array. So why is it not a string?

Comment: @Manish: seem my edit.

Comment: Is this the full stack trace ?

Comment: @ToYonos: See my edit, if you've meant that.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<resources>` tag from res/xml/defaults.xml

That file should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="PreferenceCategory A">

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="checkbox_preference"
        android:title="title_checkbox_preference"
        android:summary="summary_checkbox_preference" />

</PreferenceCategory>

<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="PreferenceCategory B">

    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="edittext_preference"
        android:title="title_edittext_preference"
        android:summary="summary_edittext_preference"
        android:dialogTitle="dialog_title_edittext_preference" />

</PreferenceCategory>
```